# How to profile view hierarchy in Latest Android studio (i.e. v3.1.1)

Tags: android, performance, hierarchyviewer, layout-inspector

I need to check the performance of my layouts (Speed of rendering/loading) and it's child views. I can't find the "**Hierarchy Viewer**" in the latest android studio also it's alternative i.e. **Layout Inspector** is there but it doesn't have a profiling feature, It can show me the view hierarchy but that's not what I need.

I have got these details from the android official link:
[https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017)

Also got the details that it has been removed in latest Android SDK:
http://tools.android.com/recent/androidsdktoolsrevision2530feb2017

If there is any solution please help me checking the loading performance of my views. I need to make a report of the same.

Please don't suggest to downgrade android studio or it's SDK.